# How to run a php script , through my php script?

Tags: php

I am writing a php script to send push notifications in 4 different mobile platforms. Every platform require its own settings to send a push notification and that means 4 different php scripts.

I could write a huge php script with all the 4 scripts inside , and with an if - ifelse statement get the job done.

However i dont find this solution neat at all... I ve seen before that you can include a php script inside another like :

```
include 'testing.php';
```

However how can i run this now? I want to execute this script from my current script and when is done , continue executing my script. Is it possible?

Comment: echo whatever is inside the `testing.php` from that file.

Comment: What do u mean? If i want to call a function in there by passing an argument?

Comment: `include()` runs an included php and after that parent php continues

Comment: Yo dawg, here's a PHP script for your PHP script so you can run a PHP script in your PHP script while you run a PHP script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including a PHP file inside another **means** that it is being called and executed at that line where the include was written.

```
<?
do something... //does some php stuff

include("another_file.php"); /* here the code of another_file.php gets "included" 
and any operations that you have coded in that file gets executed*/

do something else.. //continues doing rest of the php stuff   
?>
```

To answer your question in comments, suppose `another_file.php` has a function:

```
<?
function hi($name)
{
  echo "hi $name";
}
?>
```

You can include the file and call the function in your parent file:

parent.php:

```
<?
include("another_file.php");
hi("Me");
?>
```

Comment: If i want to run a function that is inside a php script? If i want to pass an argument from this file to that file? Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, if you have included the file in which the function is defined then you can call that function in this file

Comment: The problem is that i need to pass an argument from the current php file to that php file. Is that possible? Cause in the current file i have the "token" , which i need to pass to the "send" function of the other file

Comment: I have updated my answer, check it..

Comment: Hmm but now that though the last part of ur answer is clear , the first part is confusing..  You include the file and then you call the function. But in the beginning u said that with simple "include" will caause the script to run. So now the script will run 2 times?! i didnt downvote your answer!

Comment: If you have defined the code as a function, then just including it will not work, you will need to `call` the function, right? So in the first case IF the code is not defined as a function, but just written directly, then including will be enough. Since you said you wanted to call a function defined in the include file, I updated the answer to show you how its done.

Comment: Well is not really a function. BUT i need to pass the argument. So i will make it a function in order to be able to do that. So in the end yes is a function that needs to be called. Are you sure about that? That is good practice to include a function like that? Seems strange that in one case the code would run and in other case it wont run because is a function...

Comment: If i understand it well , with the include you literally include the code in the script. So maybe i will include all the functions in the beginning of the script , as i would do with any other function and call them as you do. Right?

Comment: Oh I am totally sure. Trust me :-) In fact, it is one of the fundamental principles to have function definitions in other files, and including them as and when required and calling their functions. What you should do is create separate files and group functions inside them, and then as and when those functions are required, include the definition file in your main file and call those functions. It is just standard practice...

Answer (score 1):

You just need to include it in the middle... as easy as that. I'll show you with an example.

```
<?php

echo "It's a nice day to send an email OR an sms.<br>";
$Platform = "mobile";

if ($Platform == "mobile")
  {
  include 'testing.php';
  }
else
  {
  include 'whatever.php';
  }

echo "The message was sent! Now I will print from 0 to 100:<br>";
for ($i = 0; $i<= 100; $i++)
  echo $i . '<br>';
?>
```

Althought, if there's more than 1 platform as you said, you might want to learn to use the [PHP switch statment](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php).

For better understanding and as I learned it:

When you use `include`, you are literately putting the code of the included file in the code you have*. Say that 'testing.php' has an echo that does `echo "Hello world";`, then the above is the same as this:

testing.php

```
<?php
echo "Hello world";
?>
```

index.php (or whatever name):

```
<?php

echo "It's a nice day to send an email OR an sms.<br>";
$Platform = "mobile";

if ($Platform == "mobile")
  {
  echo "Hello world";
  }
else
  {
  include 'whatever.php';
  }

echo "The message was sent! Now I will print from 0 to 100:<br>";
for ($i = 0; $i<= 100; $i++)
  echo $i . '<br>';
?>
```

*with a couple of exceptions: you need to put the PHP tags in the included file `<?php` `?>` and you can have multiple line acting as one (you don't need curly braces in the include).

Comment: how can i pass an argument from the current script to the script called? Is that possible? Cause the function that will run in the other php file , needs the argument to run.

Comment: can you show the other function so we understand it better, please? All the variables that are available in the current file are also available in the included file, so you just need to call the function with that variable.